# PID control action for AC reference of variable amplitude and frequency

Tags: simulink, pid-controller

i have seen example of controlling output dc voltage of DC to DC buck converter using PID controller. I want to implement DC to AC converter. I tried using PID controller. Since i am comparing output AC signal(continuously varying) with reference sinusoidal signal, PID controller is not providing expected output. In case of DC to DC, both reference signal was constant. In my case, it is continuously varying sine wave. Can anyone suggest any way to get accurate DC to AC conversion? i changed kp and ki parameters to get needed response. it is working well. but, when i change frequency of input reference signal, output signal amplitude drops and again i have to change PID parameters.
 P.S. when i change frequency of input reference signal, again i have to change PID gain parameters. Can PID controller work with continuously varying reference signal(in terms of amplitude and frequency both) ?

Comment: can some one please reply?

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer I gave to your other question:

[PID working with sine wave as reference in simulink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048052/pid-working-with-sine-wave-as-reference-in-simulink?s=7|0.0000)

If you need varying frequence for your reference, you can use a `dq0 controller` where the dq0 transform angle comes from a frequency reference (that you can change) passing through an integrator. Then set your *d* reference to the amplitude you wish.